# Sandbox Management - What parameters to be considered for managing sandboxes?

Tags: sandbox, management

I have around 10 sandboxes ranging from Developer to Config Only to Full Sandbox. I want to manage all these sandboxes and make sure all are in sync, all are up-to-date with latest deployment done, etc.

I have just started enlisting below parameters in an excel to manage. Please let me know what attributes/parameters you consider while managing the sandboxes?
1. Type of Sandbox
2. Last Date when code move completed?
3. Last Date when refreshed?
4. ??
5. ??
6. etc.

Thanks,

Vimal

Comment: *ahem* you're using an excel sheet to manage this instead of a Custom Object (in say, a DevOrg)?  ;)

Comment: great. now this starts a food for thought point :) Can you enlighten how do you manage it in Custom Object?

Comment: Like creating a custom object?  Or a good way to manage many sandboxes?   The latter is in a response below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I manage 3 production orgs (each with their own Sandboxes) + about a dozen dev orgs.  It get's very tricky knowing what Metadata is in which org (since about half of the orgs pertain to one large project, new code isn't always deployed to every org, and often, classes are in various states of development among orgs).

For your tracking, I'd say, note:

- Org Name
- Org Type (Production, Sandbox, Full-Sandbox, Developer)
- Login credentials for the master-admin (username, password, and security token) so you can always access the metadata via API (e.g. Eclipse Salesforce IDE)
- Some `Text Area` fields to track things like a `description`, `Code Updates`, etc.  (whatever you like)
- Some way to track Sandbox hierarchy:  Say you have an org with many Sandboxes.  It's a good practice to have only **1** sandbox, call it the "Master Sandbox" able to deploy change sets to the Production Org.  The idea is to have the "Master Sandbox" be a facsimile of the Production Org (metadata-wise).  That way any tests that pass in the "Master Sandbox" *should* pass in the Production.
- Maybe some URL fields for important links (e.g. files in chatter `Files`, Visualforce pages)

You could also have a Child object(s) to store a description of any changes that were made that day, who made them, implications, etc.